# How can I add a button that changes color for all backgrounds in all my Windows in xaml and c#

Tags: c#, xaml

I have already changed the background color of the window (a label) that are my buttons, but it doesn't appear the other labels from the other windows to change it too. Can someone help me?

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   label3.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
}
```

Comment: I guess you want to store value of background color which user selects and set it as background color of your control

Comment: @KevinShah yes, how can I do it

Comment: you need to create one class in which you can store color which user has selected and you have to set that color value to windows form background on your windows form load event.

Answer (score 0):

Add Style as Window.Resources or Application.Resources as below:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

I added button as an example as below:

```
<Button Name="Button1" Click="Button_Click" Style="{DynamicResource MyButtonStyle}">Button1</Button>
```

And, Add event handler for "Button_Click" as below:

```
public void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Style style = new Style { TargetType = typeof(Button) };
    style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Green));
    Resources["MyButtonStyle"] = style;
}
```

Button's color will be changed to Green when you click the button.

It comes from https://mobilechos.blogspot.com/2019/04/how-to-change-button-background-color.html what is my blog.